# Ciclo para crear botones con jquery y enviar un string como parametro

Tags: php, html

Tengo un problema al crear botones mediante un `for` y ponerle dentro del `onclick` el nombre de una función con un parámetro, pero este parámetro es una cadena, que obtengo de un `array` y al acabar el ciclo todos los botones tienen el nombre del ultimo elemento del array y no de cada posición del array.

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($formatos); $i++)
  {
?> <script type="text/javascript"> var per=<?php
    echo json_encode($formatos[$i]['idPeriodo']);
?>; </script> <button onclick="enviar(per)">Guardar</button> <?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: Acabo de editar su pregunta para añadir el código que usted dejó en el comentario, observe que ahora está diferente, puede puede ver bajo su pregunta compartir, editar, cerrar, reportar, pudiendo acceder a editar presionado sobre él, y poner o modificar su pregunta para añadir algo en este caso el código, le recomiendo que entre para que pueda ver como se formatea el código, básicamente es poner 4 espacios, pero lo puede hacer seleccionando el código en el modo edición y pulsando sobre el icono { } que está en la parte superior donde escribe el código, para futuras preguntas/respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Al parecer el problema no está en el ciclo `for` sino en cómo se han obtenido los datos que están almacenados en `$formatos`. Por favor edita la pregunta nuevamente para que puedas mostrar el código asociado a cómo agregas información en este arreglo.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente no se por que declaras una variable en javascript para almacenar el valor `$formatos[$i]['idPeriodo']` si en php puedes imprimir directamente el valor al crear los botones en el for.

Suponiendo que tu arreglo es de la siguiente forma:

```
$arr[0]['id'] = 1;
$arr[1]['id'] = 2;
$arr[2]['id'] = 3;
$arr[3]['id'] = 4;
$arr[4]['id'] = 5;
```

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $arr[0]['id'] = 1;
        $arr[1]['id'] = 2;
        $arr[2]['id'] = 3;
        $arr[3]['id'] = 4;
        $arr[4]['id'] = 5;

        for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
            echo '<button onclick="enviar('.$arr[$i]['id'].')">Guardar</button>'."<br/>";
        }
    ?>
    </body>
    <script>
       function enviar(per){
         //codigo funcion
       }
    </script>
</html>
```